# shell script for Installing the software from local machine to remote machine

Tags: networking, server, bash, scripts, ssh

Iam newbie to the shell script, i have to install the software from local machine to remote machine.
1. The script should be connect the remote machine , if it's connect then create a new folder then install the software which is located in the local machine, if the machine is not connected it shows the error message(hosts not connected).
2. If Port number 22 is not enabled, it should be bypass or use 8080 port number to  connect and install the software.Please helpme out to write and excute the script.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question has been asnwered in another post, please read this post first and if you do not get answer or if you have specific question feel free to modify your question.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92664/how-to-deploy-programs-on-multiple-machines

I am pasting the answer for your benefit. Thanks [Terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon) For this answer.

you can set up passwordless access to each of the machines easily enough using this approach:

install `sshpass` on your local machine

`sudo apt-get install sshpass`
This will allow you to pass the password as a command line argument:

`sshpass -p '<password>' ssh user@server`
Create an ssh key

`ssh-keygen -t rsa`
You can simplify things by allowing an empty passphrase (the rest of this answer will assume you have done so, let me know if your security concerns prohibit this and I will modify accordingly).

Create a file with all the IPs you are interested in and their respective username and passwords, one per line:

```
1.2.3.4 bob bobs_password
11.22.33.44 hary harrys_password
```

Now, use sshpass to copy your key files and --as long as you've used an empty passphrase-- allow passwordless access to all machines:

```
while read ip user pass; do 
  sshpass -p "$pass" ssh ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $user@$ip;
done < ips.txt
```

Now that you have passwordless access set up, install your software on each machine (this assumes that $user can run apt-get, basically that $user is root):

```
 while read ip user pass; do 
   ssh $user@$ip "apt-get install package; 
 done < ips.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Ananya, But in this script how it will pick up the software package , we should give the file(software) path right?else how it will install.

Comment: This method assumes that you have the package in the apt-get repository, it its not you can add to repository check this link. https://tecadmin.net/add-apt-repository-ubuntu/,

if you have your own shell script then you may have the file sent to remote system by sftp and run it directly.

Comment: I agree,But i should write a script like: In the script belongs to below mentioned points:1. Need to connect the remote machines(if successfully connected it will display the message or not)2. again needs to create an dir in the remote server then    3. needs to install the software automatically( path should be specified in this script only) This .msi or .dll files needs to install in the remote windows machine.